# Smartface Android publish "Key Pass" parameter

Tags: android, publish, smartface.io

When it is publishing i have followed [Publishing Procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL1qg.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL1qg.png): http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/publishing-procedures/ for android but i could not find what parameter to be entered "Key Pass" on smartface before publishig. Is it the same value "Keystore Pass" and "Key Pass" ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In command prompt, it asks you to enter values including keyPass. 
You should fill Package Properties with the values that you entered for Keystore Pass and Key Pass. 
If you want you can enter same value for two of them.

Only thing you should be careful is that, you have to enter the same value as you entered in command prompt.